# How to pass path to file as parameter MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to fill my database from file. And I want to pass path to file as parameter in sql script.

I tried this.

`LOAD DATA INFILE @fileName INTO TABLE TICKETS COLUMNS terminated BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1,@col2,@col3) set ticket_id=@col1,win_size=@col2;`

And from MySQL console:

`set @fileName = "path/to/file"`

But it didn't work.

And like this:

`set @query = CONCAT('LOAD DATA INFILE ', @fileName, ' INTO TABLE TICKETS COLUMNS terminated BY \'\\t\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\' (@col1,@col2,@col3) set ticket_id=@col1,win_size=@col2;');`

But for this there were an errors.

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/qwe.txt INTO TABLE TICKETS COLUMNS' at line 1`

`ERROR 1243 (HY000): Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE`

`ERROR 1243 (HY000): Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE`

How can I pass this?

Comment: The error seems to indicate a missing quote after the file name..

Comment: Your @query has a missing quotes to ***both*** open and terminate the file path. Your file path has spaces *(don't use spaces, they're a bad habit, but if you MUST then you need to escape them in the file path)*. Your file path uses `/` but Windows uses `\ `

Comment: @P.Salmon I tried this thing, but still not work.

Comment: why not select @query then copy and paste the result and see if it runs..

Comment: @MatBailie thanks, it really solved the problem, but another one appeared.
'\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1,@col2,@col3) set ticket_id=@col1,win_size=@c'
Maybe I'm processing '\t' and '\n' incorrectly?

Comment: For a different issue, create a new question.

Comment: @P.Salmon 20:28:13 `set @query = CONCAT('LOAD DATA INFILE \'', @fileName, '\' INTO TABLE TICKETS COLUMNS terminated BY \'\\t\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\' (@col1,@col2,@col3) set ticket_id=@col1,win_size=@col2') 0 row(s) affected 0.000 sec`

Comment: `\\t` is how you represent a \ and a t. If you want to represent a tab, you just want `\t`